# Issue with transactions in multiple services (Spring Framework/JTA): org.hibernate.ObjectDeletedException: deleted instance passed to merge

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, jta, spring-transactions

I receive the following exception during program execution:

```
org.hibernate.ObjectDeletedException: deleted instance passed to merge: [ns.entity.Category#<null>]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.ObjectDeletedException: deleted instance passed to merge: [ns.entity.Category#<null>]
```

The following code throws exception:

```
importer.foo();
```

Importer service:

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class Importer {

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @Autowired
    private CategoryService categoryService;

    @Transactional
    public void foo() {
        User user = userService.findByLogin("max");
        categoryService.delete(user.getCategories());
    }
}
```

UserService (uses CrudRepository):

```
@Service
@Repository
@Transactional
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService {

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository repository;

    @Override
    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    public User findById(Long userId) {
        return repository.findOne(userId);
    }
}
```

CategoryService (uses CrudRepository):

```
@Service
@Repository
@Transactional
public class CategoryServiceImpl implements CategoryService {

    @Autowired
    private CategoryRepository repository;

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public void delete(Set<Category> categories) {
        repository.delete(categories);
    }
}
```

The following code snippet in `CategoryServiceImpl.delete()` works without exception:

```
  for (Category category : categories) {
      Category newCat = findById(category.getCategoryId());
      if (newCat != null) {
          delete(newCat);
      }
  }
```

From what I understand two different transactions are used (one read only and one for deletion). Is it possible to re-use the transaction for all calls? Removing `(readOnly = true)` from `UserServiceImpl.findById()` does not help.

I thought that just one transaction should be used for all three methods (`Importer.foo()`, `UserServiceImpl.findById()`, `CategoryServiceImpl.delete()`) according to Spring documentation.